# How do I implement a redirects-only rack-based heroku application?

Tags: redirect, heroku, rack, http-status-code-301

I would like to create an rack application for deployment of heroku to create some 301 redirects to other subdomains.

If the path would be carried over, it would be nice.

I started with the following code, but it isn't working:

```rb
require 'rack-force_domain'

use Rack::ForceDomain, ENV["DOMAIN"]

run lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type'=>'text/plain'}, StringIO.new("Hello World!\n")] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `sinatra` finally. That's my `config.ru`:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get %r{(.*)} do
  redirect to("http://custom.domain#{params[:captures].first}"), 301
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

Answer (score 1):

Just did this and it was surprisingly simple:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rack'
gem 'rack-rewrite'
```

config.ru:

```
require 'rack/rewrite'

use Rack::Rewrite do
  ...
end

run lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type'=>'text/plain'}, StringIO.new("Nothing Here!\n")] }
```

Anything that doesn't match your redirect rules will just return a 200 with text "Nothing Here!"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rack-rewrite - https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite, it has an example for what you want to achieve.

Comment: That's how my `config.ru` looks like now.

    require 'rack/rewrite'
    use Rack::Rewrite do
      r301 %r{.*}, 'http://blog.example.com/$&'
    end

Heroku logs reports:

    Unexpected error while processing request: missing run or map statement

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the answer by @rriemann a bit.  I found that I want the full path to be redirected including params.  Also, isn't interpolating a user supplied string like that dangerous? This works for me:

```
require 'sinatra'

get "*" do
  redirect to("http://custom.domain" + request.fullpath), 301
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

Also, here is a [github link](https://github.com/marchinilab/redirector) to my implementation in case anyone wants it.